# How to combine multiple events in a Kafka Topic to new events

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I have a Kafka Topic with Json data like

```
{"storeid": 17, "data": "blablabla"}
{"storeid": 17, "data": "blublublu"}
{"storeid": 18, "data": "bliblibli"}
```

What I need is to publish new events into another topic/stream containing the combined data for same storeid when 1000 events or 5 mins (which comes first) has passed.
The expected result would be:

```
{"storeid": 17, "alldata": [{"data", "blablabla"},{"data", "blublublu"}]}
{"storeid": 18, "alldata": [{"data", "bliblibli"}]}
```

Note, the "data" property actually contains a much more complex Json but I've cut it short for brevity.

Any input as how to do that with KSQLDB or other tools?

Comment: Have you seen the docs on windowing? https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/concepts/time-and-windows-in-ksqldb-queries/

Comment: Thanks for the link. I must admit I'm pretty new in Kafka, so I'm currently tumbling around. I thought it would be a pretty common scenario...

Comment: So anyway, Windowing seems like a way to go, but how do you concatenate the data properties from each event into the Windowed events. I am aware that events are immutable so in reality new aggregated events are generated in the downstream topic

Comment: That's correct, a new stream and kafka topic (more than one topic, actually) will be created. What you're doing is a common scenario, and windowing is how you accomplish it. The only caveat is there's not an easy way to to do the "1000 events or 5 minutes, whichever comes first"... You could do a 5 minute hopping/sliding window, but then you need to count the events as you aggregate (which ksql can't really do, AFAIK, so you'd need to use Kafka Streams). Or you can try an unbounded session window to get groups of 1000 events, but could take much longer/shorter than 5 minutes

Answer (score 0):

A thumb rule with KAFKA is, once an event publish into to KAFKA topic, it can't be altered until you consume it and execute a certain number of transformation from the business logic perspective. So here, you are trying to do an absolute transformation of your data stream based on a key '**storeid**'. There are multiple way to do this, KSQL would be more preferable as you can write efficient queries to do so. Refer  https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/.

Or if you are building a Stream, and from KStream to pipe-in into another stream or topic based on a key, you can use one of the stateless transformation called '**Branch**' with predicate configuration.

### *Branch or Split input topic → KStream*

- Branch (or split) a KStream based on the supplied predicates into one or more KStream instances.
- Predicates are evaluated in order.
- A record is placed to one and only one output stream on the first match: if the n-th predicate evaluates to true, the record is placed to n-th stream. If no predicate matches, the record is dropped.
- Branching is useful, for example, to route records to different downstream topics.

  KStream<String, Long> stream = ...;

  KStream<String, Long>[] branches = stream.branch(

  ```
    (key, value) -> key.startsWith("A"), /* first predicate  */

    (key, value) -> key.startsWith("B"), /* second predicate */

    (key, value) -> true                 /* third predicate  */
  );
  ```

// KStream branches[0] contains all records whose keys start with "A"

// KStream branches[1] contains all records whose keys start with "B"

// KStream branches[2] contains all other records

Comment: thanks for picking this up. Since I'm pretty new into Kafka, I was wondering if you could be a bit more specific. The terms Branching and/or Splitting doesn't really ring a bell to me when it comes to KSQLDB. Also KStream???

Comment: @Nikolaj KSQL is built on top of the KStream api... But branching will not help you aggregate data from the same keys